# css3 animation using transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

First li in line of several ones doesn't glue to the next one if the first one smoothly derceases to 0 using css3 animation via transform property. Why?

Working sourcecode example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lLpeo

Thanx

Comment: you used first-child ?

Comment: `:first-child` is in deed the FIRST child of `ul` element, not first in each line...

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uwtbk check this

Comment: umm, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he wants the second `<li>` to move left as the first one becomes smaller to finally "disappear"...

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKrhB ? Then you need a `-webkit-transform-origin: right center;`

Comment: Is this the kind of effect you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FIceH

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `scaleX`. It actually doesn't change the size of the li but scales it. I think the solution is to use `width` property http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lIbyC

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'movement'{
    to {
        width: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: To preserve ease of editing, you can leave off the `from` keyframe and the browser will construct the keyframe from the values already set.

Comment: Sure, that was just an example to show that another CSS property should be used. Thanks for the note!

Comment: I need the first and third li move smoothly left according decreasing width of the first. I think I understood the problem - scale don't decrease width. It just turns the container. To use transform proerty is the requirement of the test task.

Comment: @user3734045, so the 1st li should move? Or it's width should decrease? Or both?

Comment: just first should decrease its width. Other li should move left

Comment: @Olejek, if the condition is to use `transform` - try this overflow work-around: http://jsbin.com/noxezagi/3/edit. But manipulating `width` property for such task looks much better.